# Length property for PictureBox not working

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to use:

```
PictureBox1.Length
```

but I get the following error:

> Error 3 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Length is a property of a one-dimensional object.  PB has two.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.Height` and `.Width` properties.

Answer (score 2):

The [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) control does not have a `Length` Property.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_properties.aspx) is a list of all properties for a `PictureBox`.  What are you trying to do?

You might want to look at [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx) and [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx)

Comment: okay.. I guess .width will work..

not I have a problem.. I am initializing and array of objects, i need something like this:

Greyhound[1].StartingPosition = pictureBox1.Location;
Greyhound[2].StartingPosition = pictureBox2.Location;
and so on..

but I need to make it by a loop
for ( ......... )
{
Greyhound[i].StartingPosition = ????????? // what should go here??
}

Comment: What is your goal? Are Greyhound Form's? Controls?

Comment: You can blame Head First C# for this one. It tells you to use PictureBox's Length property in this particular exercise.